# JFormattedTextField for floats

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

When using a `JFormattedTextField` for floats, I'm unable to see the part after the dot. For instance: if I fill in 3.14, the formatted text field replaces this to 3?

```
JFormattedTextField aR = new JFormattedTextField(new Float(0.00));

aR.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new PropertyChangeListener() {        
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(evt.getNewValue());      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
For instance: if I fill in 3.14, the formatted text field replaces this to 3?
```

Not likely `3`, but `3.1`.

**Because** when you call the constructor new `JFormattedTextField(Object)`,it calls `setValue(object)` function which will eventually try to create a `formatter factory` corresponding to the Type of `object value` by calling `getDefaultFormatterFactory(Object type)` function, in which the default `formatter` for `float` is created as follows:

```
if (type instanceof Number) {
            AbstractFormatter displayFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
            ((NumberFormatter)displayFormatter).setValueClass(type.getClass());
            AbstractFormatter editFormatter = new NumberFormatter(
                                  new DecimalFormat("#.#"));
            ((NumberFormatter)editFormatter).setValueClass(type.getClass());

            return new DefaultFormatterFactory(displayFormatter,
                                               displayFormatter,editFormatter);
        }
```

From this code, you should have noticed that it creates the `DecimalFormat` with mask `"#.#"`. 
So try adding the `DecimalFormat` with mask `"#.##"` in the `JFormattedTextField` constructor:

```
JFormattedTextField feild = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("#.##"));
feild.setValue(new Float(3.34));
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

- you would need to set number of decimal placed in `NumberFormat`, `DecimalNumberFormat`

. e.g.

```
    FormattedTextField.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

        @Override
        public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
            NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
            format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
            formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
            formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
            formatter.setMaximum(1000.00);
            return formatter;
        }
    });
```

- maybe to use `DocumentListener` for `JTextComponent`s instead of `PropertyChangeListener`, depends on if you want to listening for all changes or final result is important only